# Zoom and Pane UI Elements for Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, dictionary, svg, zooming, snap.svg

I'm using Snap.svg for the presentation of my svg on a webpage. This works fine and I already implemented a zoom and a pane modus of the map by using the scroll wheel and the "dragging" technique.
 In case of no availability of a mouse, I would like to integrate ui elements for zooming and panning.

As implementing them by using input-range elements and custom arrows seems not to be the best option, I would like to ask if someone knows a library or something else, where such map ui elements are provided. I only found those in combination of the use of the respective system (leaflet,mapbox,google, etc.), but not for general use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use leaflet for svg presentation surprisingly easily. Take a look at this example:

http://kempe.net/blog/2014/06/14/leaflet-pan-zoom-image.html

Then replace the URL in that example to your local svg. Instant pan/zoom for your svg!